# create SQLite MyDb also creates webview*.*

Tags: android, sqlite, webview

So I've been successfully creating Android SQLite db's by extending SQLiteOpenHelper for a few weeks now.

Is there some way I can PREVENT any/all of the webview*.* db files from being created?
What are they for? 
I don't believe I need them? At least not yet?

root@cdma_spyder:/data/data/com.ntier.android.MyApp/databases # ls -al

```
24576 2014-09-29 15:51 MyDbProvider.db
8720  2014-09-29 15:51 MyDbProvider.db-journal

40960 2014-09-29 15:51 webview.db
8720  2014-09-29 15:51 webview.db-journal
7168 2014-09-29 15:51 webviewCookiesChromium.db
0 2014-09-29 15:56 webviewCookiesChromiumPrivate.db
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there some way I can PREVENT any/all of the webview*.* db files from being created?

Get rid of all `WebView` widgets in your app.

> What are they for?

They are for use by `WebView`, for caching and cookie purposes.

Comment: I have not created any WebView widgets in my app. BUT my app uses Google Map objects. Is that the reason for their creation?

Comment: @JDOaktown: If by "Google Map objects" you mean the native Android Maps V2 from the Play Services framework, AFAIK that does not involve a `WebView`. Note that if you have ads integrated into your app, ad networks might be using a `WebView` as part of how they display certain ad types.

Comment: OOPS. Thank you so much for your response. It made me rethink. I believe the webview junk is created from the google ad on my app.